# Integrating keyboard use with answer randomization in Qualtrics

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

I'm using qualtrics to present a user with two choices, one on the left and one on the right. I'd like to have them use the keyboard arrow keys to make a selection and I currently have code to let them do this using the following:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
    /*Place Your Javascript Below This Line*/

this.hideNextButton();
this.hidePreviousButton();

var that = this;

Event.observe(document, 'keydown', function keydownCallback(e) {
    var qid = this.questionId;
    var order = $("QR~"+qid+"~DisplayOrder").value.split("|");
    var left = order[0];
    var right = order[1];


  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 37: // 'L' was pressed
      choiceID = left
      break;
    case 39: // 'R' was pressed
      choiceID = right
      break;
  }

  if (choiceID) {
    Event.stopObserving(document, 'keydown', keydownCallback);
    that.setChoiceValue(choiceID, true);
    that.clickNextButton();
  }
});

    });
```

If the answers are randomized and questions are not reversed it works fine. If the answers are reversed it will select the option on the right when the left arrow key is pressed, and vice versa. I suspect I need some way to set the choice ID to the ID of what is actually presented, or completely change the third and sixth lines, but some of the more promising functions in the API don't seem to pan out. Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the display order of the randomized choices, then assign values to left and right (I'm assuming this is a simple multiple choice question):

```
var qid = this.questionId;
var order = $("QR~"+qid+"~DisplayOrder").value.split("|");
var left = order[0];
var right = order[1];
```

Then, in your code:

```
switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 37: // 'L arrow' was pressed
        choiceID = left
        break;
    case 39: // 'R arrow' was pressed
        choiceID = right
        break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It doesn't seem to be working for me though. It is a simple multiple choice question with one option presented on the left and one on the right.

Comment: I did update it after my initial post.  I forgot the .value. in the second line.  Check to make sure you have that.  I tried the first part of the code and it works (assigns randomized values of 1/2 to left/right).

Comment: Ok - I'm still having trouble but this may be my ineptitude with Javascript. I've edited the original question with the entirety of my entry in Qualtrics. Thoughts?

Comment: The lines starting with var qid through var right should be outside the event.observe.  I would put them right after hidePreviousButton.