# How to integrate a keyboard response in qualtrics using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

I am interested in having users respond to questions in Qualtrics by using the left and right arrow keys using a JavaScript code. The question type will be a single response multiple-choice question. I would like to "hide" the next button and have participants respond only using the arrow keys. When they select the "right" arrow, I would like the "right" response to be selected and for the question to auto-advance to the next item.

I found a similar code here: [Integrating keyboard use with answer randomization in Qualtrics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28976286/integrating-keyboard-use-with-answer-randomization-in-qualtrics).

```
 Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
    /*Place Your Javascript Below This Line*/

this.hideNextButton();
this.hidePreviousButton();

var qid = this.questionId;
var order = $("QR~"+qid+"~DisplayOrder").value.split("|");
var left = order[0];
var right = order[1];

var that = this;

Event.observe(document, 'keydown', function keydownCallback(e) {

switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 37: // 'L arrow' was pressed
        choiceID = left
        break;
    case 39: // 'R arrow' was pressed
        choiceID = right
        break;
}

  if (choiceID) {
    Event.stopObserving(document, 'keydown', keydownCallback);
    that.setChoiceValue(choiceID, true);
    that.clickNextButton();
  }
});

    });
```

My code should not include randomization, however. For every response, the left most option will be a "left arrow" and the right most option will be a "right arrow" and should be answered using the keyboard.

I am wondering if there is a) a problem with the code, and/or b) if the problem is specific to the response ID type?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

[Edited to show code I am attempting to use] *****

Comment: The code you copied from the original question was wrong. Read the comments under the accepted answer.

Comment: @T.Gibbons Even when I put the   

switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 37: // 'L arrow' was pressed
        choiceID = left
        break;
    case 39: // 'R arrow' was pressed
        choiceID = right
        break;
}

into my code and change the location of the var qid to var right under "hidePreviousButton" the code still does not work.

Comment: I edited the original post to show the code I used.

Comment: Are you running in split screen preview mode? If so, you need to click in the window before key presses will be recognized.

Comment: I attempted to click in the window before the key press but it still did not recognize the key press. Additionally, when I click the correct response with the mouse it does not auto-advance.